# How can I fix the broken Icon on React Native Galio-Framework?

Tags: react-native, icons

I am developing React Native app (not expo) using Galio-Framework.
https://galio.io/docs/#/components

I was trying to use `Checkbox` using sample code.
Here is the code I get from the sample.

```
<Checkbox color="primary" flexDirection="row-reverse" label="row-reverse checkbox" />
<Checkbox color="info" initialValue={true} label="initialValue set to true" />
<Checkbox color="error" initialValue={true} label="different icon" iconFamily="font-awesome" iconName="plane" />
<Checkbox color="warning" labelStyle={{ color: '#FF9C09' }} label="labelStyle used here" />
```

Unfortunately, I faced the broken icons.

[Here is bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jub8W.png)

My environment :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^5.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.9",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "galio-framework": "^0.8.0",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.2.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.63.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "1.265.0",
    "react-native-divider": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.11.3",
    "react-native-lightbox": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "0.7.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-ui-lib": "^3.39.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "victory-native": "^31.0.0"
  },
```

Somebody help me.
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open android/app/build.gradle
- Add `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"`